# removeAllDeliveredNotifications on watchOS3

Tags: swift, push-notification, watchkit, watchos, nsusernotification

How can I remove delivered notifications on watchOS?

```
override func willActivate() {
    super.willActivate()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
}
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out, does it work on WatchOS?

Comment: Not work. I just use "sendMessage" let iOS app to do that.